# alpine: apk not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

i have been trying to install some packages using apk

at first i got the apk not found error so i tried adding PATH="${PATH}:/sbin" to my ENVs

but it still says apk not found

this is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM codestrongbiz/jdk16-maven-docker:latest

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    APP_SLEEP=0 \
    JAVA_OPTS="" \

    # adding /sbin (system binaries) to container's PATH. In order for apk to add packages
    PATH="${PATH}:/sbin"

# add directly the jar
ADD *.jar /app.jar

# A command which adds some packages to docker image. Added in order to solve the font error: "Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager"
RUN apk add freetype-dev libgcc libc6-compat gcompat

EXPOSE 8087
CMD echo "The application will start in ${APP_SLEEP}s..." && \
    sleep ${APP_SLEEP} && \
    java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an alpine based image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*codestrongbiz/jdk16-maven-docker:latest* image is debian based

You can use there *dpkg* or *apt-get* for package installation.

Here is the output of *cat /etc/*release* inside of a running container:

```bash
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

As suggested in the comment by @David Maze, to get into the interactive debugging shell:

```
docker run --rm -it IMAGE_NAME sh
```

*sh* can be changed to a *bash*, it depends on the image.
There you can test commands before writing dockerfile.

Comment: (I might prefer to `docker run --rm -it the-image sh` or `bash`; that will make the interactive debugging shell the main container process, and you won't need a separate `docker exec`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze, thanks! I've mentioned it in the answer.